# Looking for peculiar vector transformation

Tags: probability, transformation, vectors

I have a vector of numbers from 0 to 1. For example:
[0.5, 0.5, 0.1]. I need to find a transformation which increases sum of the vector to asked number and:
-keeps the order of elements (if element1 was bigger than element2 it needs to stay that way)
-numbers stay in 0 - 1 range
-differences between elements are kept relatively close (if elements are close to each other in value they are close in value after the transformation); if possible for every four elements where a1>b1 and a2>b2 if a1-b1 > a2-b2 it stays that way after the transformation
-for any two elements a and b if a > b then (1-a')/(1-a) < (1-b)/(1-b') where a' and b' are elements after the transformation; that is the distance to 1 decreases relatively more for bigger elements than for lower ones;

Last point needs an example. Let's say I want to transform [0.8, 0.1, 0.1] to a vector of sum 2. The easiest way to do it is to move every element halfway to 1 arriving at: [0.9, 0.55, 0.55]. What I want is a transformation which moves 0.8 the most and 0.1 and 0.1 less. 
One try would be to apply a function (let's say x**2), like this:
(code in Python but it should be easily readable for non programmers)

```
def transform(v, newsum, func):
    F = sum([func(x) for x in v])
    oldsum = sum(v)
    return [x + (newsum-oldsum)*func(x)/F for x in v]
```

This satisfies a requirement that biggest elements move more, like in this example:

```
>>> transform([0.5, 0.5, 0.1], 2, lambda x: x*x)
[0.9411764705882353, 0.9411764705882353, 0.11764705882352942]
```

but it has a flow that elements after a transformation may exceed 1:

```
>>> transform([0.8, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1], 2.4, lambda x: x*x)
[1.3688888888888886, 0.5422222222222222, 0.37999999999999995, 0.1088888888888889]
```

Part 2:
The same problem, but now there are is another vector of weights and the goal is to make a transformation for required weighted sum (weights * numbers in resulting vector (weights stay unchanged) sum up to required number).

I need this transformation for adjusting vectors in huge decision tree so it would be great if it's not very computationally expensive (sorting would be painful for example but probably acceptable).

Comment: It seems to me that what you are asking for is not a vector transformation but a function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ that acts on each element separately and satisfies some conditions. Is that right?

Comment: I am looking for a function f: (v, newsum) -> v where newsum is a sum of elements in resulting vector and elements in resulting vector are in [0,1] (as well as they satisfy other mentioned constraints).

Comment: May be I misunderstand but your constraints are in terms of what happens to individual elements. If $f(x)$ is what becomes of element $x$ you want it to stay in $[0,1]$, move to the right so $f(x)>x$, bigger to bigger so $f$ is monotone increasing, and compress more near $0$ than near $1$. These are already incompatible, if $f$ is monotone increasing with graph above $y=x$ but within $[0,1]$ it will necessarily move numbers near $0$ more than near $1$, think $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: The sum of all elements in resulting vector must be equal to given number so it's not about individual elements only. As to: "These are already incompatible" I meant that distance between an element and 1 decreases relatively more, that is the new_distance_to_1/old_distance_to_1 is lower for bigger elements. In example I gave above with [0.8, 0.1, 0.1] -> [0.9, 0.55, 0.55) those ratios are 0.5 0.5 0.5 (every distance to 1 was reduced by half) while I want the distance of the biggest element to be reduced more. Please feel free to edit OP if you see a way to express in a clearer way.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how exactly you measure the distance decrease, you have to either give up $f(x)>x$ or decrease is lower closer to $1$, they contradict each other.

Comment: No they don't. For example you could sort the elements, and turn the biggest one to 1 and do that until you reach required sum. Then subtract epsilon from the biggest element, 2 epsilons from 2nd one etc. This way you achieved the goal of lesser distances decreasing more but you violated another requirement that elements close to each other stay that way. For example [0.8, 0.1, 0.1] would be turned into [1, 0.9, 0.1] or [0.8, 0.11, 0.09] into [1, 0.91, 0.09]. While I want 2nd and 3rd elements having similar increase as they are close to each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15525/discussion-between-piotr-lopusiewicz-and-conifold).

Answer (score 1):

Since the element values are supposed to stay close to each other the new value $f(x)$ has to be a continuous function of the old one $x$, and $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ to keep them within $[0,1]$. To shift $x$ up we must have $f(x)\geq x$, and for larger to go to larger $f$ must be monotone increasing. The relative distance decrease condition is that the ratio of distances $\frac{1-f(x)}{1-x}$ is monotone decreasing.

It is convenient to make the change $\varphi(x):=1-f(1-x)$, then still $\varphi:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ and $\varphi$ is monotone increasing, but $f(x)\geq x$ becomes $\varphi(x)\leq x$ and the distance ratio decrease condition simplifies to 
$\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}$ being monotone increasing. The family $\varphi_n(x)=x^n$ with $n>1$ obviously satisfies all the conditions, leading to $f_n(x)=1-(1-x)^n$. With $n=2$ for example this transforms $[0.8,0.1,0.1]$ to $[0.96,0.19,0.19]$ with new/old distance ratios of $0.2,0.9,0.9$.

Since $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_n(x)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$ for $x>0$ it is possible to make the sum of elements into any value between the original sum and $d$, the number of elements, by adjusting $n$. Solving for a particular sum $S$ isn't pleasant though, one has to solve $d-\sum_{k=1}^d(1-x_k)^n=S$ for $n$. It can be done with Newton's iteration to some accuracy, solving $d-d(1-\bar{x})^{n_0}=S$, where $\bar{x}$ is the average of $x_k$, gives $n_0$ for the initial guess. Alternatively, $\varphi$ can be chosen piecewise linear, reducing distance ratios more crudely, with the break point(s) and the value(s) at it serving as parameters, equation(s) for them should be easier to solve.